# How to see code in the console [Python, Tkinter, Atom]

Tags: python, tkinter, atom-editor

I am using Atom to do this, I am asking how to view a variable in the console while also having the TKinter GUI loaded.

My code is as follows:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

rd1 = random.randint(1, 20)

root.mainloop()
```

Running the program only shows the `tk` window but I am wondering how I can view the outcome of `rd1` from the console, without having to display it in the GUI.
The console becomes a black ver and will only display text when closing the GUI.
Text as follows:

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 1.298 s
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Can't you just add `print(rd1)` after `rd1 = ...` or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

printing it will show it in the console; sometime it is buffered, so you can add the optional argument `flush=True` to the print statement.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

rd1 = random.randint(1, 20)
print(rd1, flush=True)      # flush will output immediately

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ohh. Duhhh! I completely forgot to print it. For some reason i asumed it would show up